# Node js : Call an async function in the same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a function defined in a file which calls an async function and also a normal function. I have defined them in this way

```
const cms_service = {
    fetchSinglePost: function(post){
        const image = await cms_service.fetchImageData(post)
        let single_post = {
            post: cms_service.fetchPostData(post),
            image: image
        }
        return single_post
    },
    fetchPostData: function (post) {
        var post_response = {
            id: post.data[0].id
        }
        return post_response
    },
    fetchImageData: async function (post) {
        let storyplay_response = {}
        if(typeof post.data[0].tmc_storyplay[0] !== 'undefined' && post.data[0].tmc_storyplay[0]){
            const storyplay = await axios.get(cms_service_url+"tmc_storyplay/"+post.data[0].tmc_storyplay[0], requestHeader);
            storyplay_response = {
                id: storyplay.data.id
            }
        }
        return storyplay_response
    }
}
module.exports = cms_service;
```

But it throws me an error saying

> TypeError: this.fetchPostData is not a function

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` keyword doesn't make sense in this context. Let's try to re-write by wrapping in object name as following:

```
const yourObj = {
 foo: () => 1,
 bar: () => yourObj.foo(),
}

module.exports = yourObject;
```

Comment: I did the structure as per this. But I dont get the data returned from the async function "fetchImageData". How can I fix this?

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar you have to use `await` with the asynchronous calls.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah. I tried it like this - post: await cms_service.fetchPostData(post). But it throws unknown identifier error

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar I just noticed that `fetchPostData` doesn't return anything. It assigns a variable and that is it. Same thing with `fetchImageData`

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you're keen for. I saw a few problems in your code. If you wish to have something return of `fetchImageData`, you have to return your modified data like: `return { id: storyplay.data.id }`. Then you get the result: `const yourData = await yourService.fetchImageData(yourPost)`

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry I missed the return statements. I edited it in the code

Comment: Can you please post full code to use your above module?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I tried this - const yourData = await yourService.fetchImageData(yourPost). But it didnt return any data

Comment: I didn't get your full context at all. But I'm also aware of you have had a condition check at the beginning of the function so you might have to check if that check is passed or it won't return nothing

Comment: @tmhao2005 I edited the code with your structure. But the fetchImageData does not return me any data. It does go through the condition. I'm sure of it

Comment: If so, try to print out the returned data `storyplay ` from axios. Let's see then

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar Did you log the result returned from axios?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your service a bit. You can access object key-values within that object.

```
const cms_service = () => {
    const fetchSinglePost = function(post){
        const image = await fetchImageData(post)
        let single_post = {
            post: fetchPostData(post),
            image: image
        }
        return single_post
    };

    const fetchPostData = function (post) {
        var post_response = {
            id: post.data[0].id
        }
        return post_response
    };

    const fetchImageData = async function (post) {
        let storyplay_response = {}
        if(typeof post.data[0].tmc_storyplay[0] !== 'undefined' && post.data[0].tmc_storyplay[0]){
            const storyplay = await axios.get(cms_service_url+"tmc_storyplay/"+post.data[0].tmc_storyplay[0], requestHeader);
            storyplay_response = {
                id: storyplay.data.id
            }
        }
        return storyplay_response
    };
}
module.exports = cms_service;
```